# Как в DataFrame правильно изменить отфильтрованные значения?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

Есть сет данных (для данного вопроса не важно какой). В нем я пытаюсь отфильтровать некие данные в некотором столбце по некоторым условиям, чтобы потом умножить эти отфильтрованные данные на какую-то константу. А потом эти же отфильтрованные измененные данные мне нужно вернуть обратно в оригинальный сет данных, чтобы записались только измененные данные.

Я пробую так:

```
train.loc[(train['car_age'] > 2) & (train['car_age'] < 6), 'price'] = \
     train.query('car_age > 2 & car_age < 6')['price'] * 0.98
```

Но это не обновляет данные в оригинальном сете данных.

Если я делаю так:

```
train['price'] = train.query('car_age > 2 & car_age < 6')['price'] * 0.98
```

То естественно, что данные в таблице `train['price']` приходят в негодность, так как в оригинальном сет данных условно всего 100 записей, а я пытаюсь добавить только 20 ранее отфильтрованных и измененных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mask = train.eval("2 < car_age < 6")
train.loc[mask, 'price'] *= 0.98
```